# Hello, need to solve a problem like such:

Tags: python, python-3.x

If the number in the line is already wroten, I must print `0` and if it's not, I must print `1`.
Got `ValueError` and tried to catch it, but it fails.

```
a=int(input())
b=input()
n='1 '
c=b.split()
for i in range(a-1):
 l=c[0]
 c.remove(l)
 d=c.index(l)
 try:
  a=a
 except ValueError as ve:
  if d > 0:
   c = c.replace(l,'zero')
  else:
   c=c.replace(l,'one')
for amogus in range(a):
 a=a.replace('one',1)
 a=a.replace('zero',0)
print(a)
```

The error tracebacks like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.pys3", line 8, in <module>
    d=c.index(l)
ValueError: '1' is not in list
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: *c* is a list. *l* has a value of '1'. There is no string with a value of '1' in the list

Comment: Side note: whitespace is your friend. `b = input()` and `c = b.split()`, putting a blank line before your `for` loops and after an indented body, etc. would dramatically help readability. And please _never_ use single-space indentation! It's very hard to read, and in a whitespace-sensitive language like Python it can easily lead to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your loop is like this:

```py
for i in range(a-1):
    l = c[0]
    c.remove(l)
    d = c.index(l)
```

`l` is set to the first item in the list `c`. You then remove that item. The last line above then tries to find the index of that item again. This will work if there is another one, but if not will throw the error you report.

Did you mean to put the last line inside the `try:`?

```py
for i in range(a-1):
    l = c[0]
    c.remove(l)
    try:
        d = c.index(l)
    except ValueError as ve:
        if d > 0:
            c = c.replace(l,'zero')
        else:
            c = c.replace(l,'one')
```

Now a friendly warning: if this fixes the reported error you will encounter another one.